# Discord.py ctx.message.delete() raises error in cog

Tags: python, discord.py

I recently moved my bot into cogs, but with that came some troubles. I have a command that will make the bot repeat a message when you invoke the command. I want the bot to delete the command that invokes the message and then send the message you typed. I have this (note: this worked when it wasn't in a cog):

```
@commands.command()
    async def say(self, ctx, *, arg=None):
        if arg is None:
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention} Tell me what to say!')
        if len(arg) > 50:
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention} That's too long!")
        else:
            await ctx.message.delete()
            await ctx.send(f'''{arg}
    - {ctx.message.author.mention}''')
```

The code runs and deletes the message that invoked the command and sends the message, but it still throws an error:

```
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 NOT FOUND (error code: 10008): Unknown Message
```

Any ways to fix this? Again the command works but it still throws and error.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: After some testing I think I have found the issue. Another problem with my code is resulting in this issue, this code in itself isn't causing the error.

Just so if others are having a similar issue when moving to cogs, my code had an on_message listener in a cog. I mistakenly added a `await self.client.process_commands(message)`

You do not need this in a cog.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try of this code.

````py
@commands.command()
    async def say(self, ctx, *, arg=""):
        if arg == "":
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention} Tell me what to say!')
        elif len(arg) > 50:
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention} That's too long!")
        else:
            await ctx.message.delete()
            await ctx.send(f"```{arg}
    - {ctx.message.author.mention}```")
````

Comment: Thank you for answering. Your code works as well, but it still throws the unknown message error from above. I think the issue is with the context but I'm not sure exactly what.

Comment: @ZippoTown aren't you supposed to pass context??

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because you are trying to get the author of the message that you just deleted. Changing `ctx.message.author.mention` to `ctx.author.mention` should fix this error.

````py
@commands.command()
async def say(self , ctx , * , arg=""):
    if arg == "":
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} Tell me what to say!')
    elif len(arg) > 50:
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} That's too long!")
    else:
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.send(f"```{arg}
    - {ctx.author.mention}```")
````

Good Luck! :D